# Late answer review ban - two controversial cases

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just got a two-day ban by conservatively reviewing the "Late Answers" section.

The first case is this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15733939

Well, this surely is not a good answer. But in my opinion, this is trying to answer the question, since logs are often helpful enough to solve the problem.

> Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still an answer. You can downvote such posts to signal that the answer is a bad answer, but it is still an answer. *[When to flag as not an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)*

This also falls in the same category: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15744826

Doesn't looks good, but it doesn't subject to a flag either.

The problem with downvoting is: downvoting isn't free (and somewhat discouraged), and I hesitate to do them frequently.

Comment: Oh, suggesting to read the logs now count as an answer? Would the same apply for suggesting to read the error message displayed in the browser? Or suggesting to re-read the code? No, this is obivously not an answer and when the write can't post a comment, then he should move on instead of writing that as an answer.

Comment: Who says downvoting is discouraged? How will anyone know that anything is wrong if the rest of us don't provide feedback?

Comment: For second post: The answer does not even try to answer the question: Op explicitly asks for a **static code analysis** method. How is "use print" an answer to this?

Comment: `downvoting isn't free (and somewhat discouraged)` Can you explain how you came to the understand that downvoting is discouraged, as if that is written guidance, it needs corrected. Voting, in general, (up or down) is heavily encouraged. And you shouldn't do one without being willing to do the other.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*"No action needed"* is obviously a wrong choice for both linked cases.
*Both* could do with a downvote at very least.

If you're not comfortable downvoting them, then ***skip*** the review.

Skipping is always better than choosing the wrong option.

Answer (score 7):

> But in my opinion, this is trying to answer the question, since logs are often helpful enough to solve the problem.

That conclusion doesn't follow from your premise.  Just because logs can be helpful in solving problems doesn't mean, "look at the logs" is an answer to the question.  It's *not* an answer to the question, not at all.

The same general reasoning applies to the other answer.

> downvoting isn't free (and somewhat discouraged), and I hesitate to do them frequently.

Downvoting isn't discouraged at all.  Downvoting bad content is *extremely important* and *highly* useful.  If you're not prepared to downvote bad content then you have no business using that review queue at all, as that's a significant portion of its purpose.